# CORS error, even though HTTP request is successful when coming from component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Before, I had been making successful fetches from directly in my 
ImageList component. Since incorporating Redux, I want to have the request done by a Saga, and have the resulting data sent to the store. However, when I attempt to make requests via a Saga, I get the CORS browser error:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://api.hopohop.com/API/TourService.asmx/GetToursByCity' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-headers in preflight response.

The entirety of the request is the same as when I was successful in the Component.

Are there any obvious reasons this may be happening? The error implies to me that it's the server's issue

Answer (score 0):

To anyone seeing this in the future, make good use of the network tab in devtools when you get CORS error. The body of the request has to match it's signature (format) exactly. That's where my mistake was.